# How to open new tab with add-on?

Tags: firefox-addon

I need firefox browser open a new tab. But this code below open new window.

```
window.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    var doc = event.originalTarget;
    var origEl = event.target || event.srcElement;
    if(origEl.tagName === 'A' || origEl.tagName === 'a') {
        tabs[0]=window.open("http://giaiphapthuonghieu.vn","http://giaiphapthuonghieu.vn");
    }
}, false);
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? What do you mean by saying "open a new tab"?

Comment: @Hatul It's a firefox-addon question. I corrected the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:
`var tab = gBrowser.loadOneTab('http://giaiphapthuonghieu.vn', {referrerURI: Services.io.newURI('http://giaiphapthuonghieu.vn', null, null)});`

So your code would look like this:

```
window.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    var doc = event.originalTarget;
    var origEl = event.target || event.srcElement;
    if(origEl.tagName === 'A' || origEl.tagName === 'a') {
        tabs[0] = gBrowser.loadOneTab('http://giaiphapthuonghieu.vn', {referrerURI: Services.io.newURI('http://giaiphapthuonghieu.vn', null, null)});
    }
}, false);
```

Comment: Good solution. Please tell me method to open a new tab with chrome add-on?

Comment: I don't know about Google Chrome. I only do Firefox. :(

Answer (score 0):

You can give only one url at once in `window.open` and use `_blank` to open in new tab instead of window

```
tabs[0]=window.open("http://giaiphapthuonghieu.vn" '_blank');
tabs[0].focus();//to focus tab
```

Comment: I added but Add-on is opened new window. It's only correct with javascript onpage.

Comment: @Manwal I thought giving `target` of `_blank` would set it to new window? Is this an accepted standard that if `_blank` is provided it opens to new tab?

Comment: I find that the `target` attribute is not honored in links in tabs opened by (SDK) add-ons.